# Identify duplicated character strings in columns in R

Tags: r, duplicates, rows

I have a data frame with 4 columns and 3000 rows. My aim is to check for every row if there are four different character strings in the columns. For example:

First row: Greece – Russia – Spain – Netherlands
Second row: England – Germany – Germany - Iran
Third row: Netherlands – Netherlands – Britain – Greece

Thus, R should give me row 2 and 3, because there are duplicates. 
Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN =1` to loop through the rows, check whether the `length` of the `unique` elements in each row is not equal to the number of columns of the dataset to get a logical vector, and this can be used to subset the rows of the dataset having at least one duplicate in a row.

```
df1[apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))!=ncol(df1),]
#       col1        col2    col3   col4
#2     England     Germany Germany   Iran
#3 Netherlands Netherlands Britain Greece
```

---

Another option is regex based method (should be faster) where we `paste` the elements of each rows, and `grep` to get the index of duplicated string rows with regex to subset the rows.

```
df1[grep("(\\b\\S+\\b)(?=.*\\1+)", do.call(paste, df1), perl = TRUE),]
#          col1        col2    col3   col4
# 2     England     Germany Germany   Iran
# 3 Netherlands Netherlands Britain Greece
```

#### Benchmarks

```
df2 <- df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), 1e6),]
system.time(df2[apply(df2, 1L, anyDuplicated),])
# user  system elapsed 
#  34.34    0.22   34.90 

system.time(df2[grep("(\\b\\S+\\b)(?=.*\\1+)", do.call(paste, df2), perl = TRUE),])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   9.53    0.05    9.61 

system.time(df2[apply(df2, 1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))!=ncol(df2),])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  41.48    0.17   41.71
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("Greece", "England", "Netherlands"), 
col2 = c("Russia", "Germany", "Netherlands"), col3 = c("Spain", 
"Germany", "Britain"), col4 = c("Netherlands", "Iran", "Greece"
 )), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first version (apply) and it worked perfectly. Unfortunately I have multiple NA values. Duplicated NAs should not be listed. So if a row is Britain - Germany - NA - NA, I don't want to see this row. I would be glad if you have a solution for this problem.

Comment: @Lilly We can create a logical index to subset the rows where there are no NAs in that row i.e. `i1 <- rowSums(is.na(df1))==0` Use that index to subset the rows,  and do the `apply` part, `apply(df1[i1, ], 1, FUN = ..`

Comment: In this case, rows like 'Britain - Britain - NA - NA' (duplicated record - Britain) wouldn't be identified, but I want to have these cases listed... i'm sorry, it's a bit complicated.

Comment: @Lilly Try `df1[apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x)  {x1 <- x[!is.na(x)]; length(unique(x1))!=length(x1) }), ]`

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_new <- df %>% 
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
    gather(key, value, -row) %>% 
    group_by(row, value) %>% 
    mutate(n = n()) %>% 
    mutate(duplicate = ifelse(n > 1, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
    # STOP HERE IF YOU WANT TO SEE DUPLICATES 
    filter(duplicate == TRUE) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    # RUN DISTINCT IF YOU JUST WANT TO SEE ROWS WITH DUPES
    distinct(row)
```

Benchmark with 3000 rows

```
dfL <- Reduce(rbind, list(df)[rep(1L, times=1000)])
system.time( ... )
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.004   0.000   0.004
```

Comment: @akrun You're 100% right, but with 3000 rows its pretty user-friendly :)

Comment: Could be, but again the number of lines you need to write is a bit of concern for me.